# Python | accessing dll using ctypes

Tags: python, windows, firefox, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to access some functions in a dll (**nss3.dll**) that ships with Firefox web browser. To handle this task I have used ctypes in Python. The problem is that it fails at the initial point which is when loading the dll in to the memory.

This is the code snippet that I have to do so.

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> windll.LoadLibrary("E:\\nss3.dll")
```

The exception I'm getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    windll.LoadLibrary("E:\\nss3.dll")
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I also tried loading it from the Firefox installation path assuming that there maybe dependencies.

```
>>> windll.LoadLibrary("F:\\Softwares\\Mozilla Firefox\\nss3.dll")
```

But I'm getting the same exception as mentioned above.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Windows DLL and not a C DLL?  Have you tried `cdll.LoadLibrary` from the ctypes library?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

nss3.dll is linked to the following DLLs, which are all located in the Firefox directory: nssutil3.dll, plc4.dll, plds4.dll, nspr4.dll, and mozcrt19.dll. The system library loader looks for these files in the DLL search path of the process, which includes the application directory, system directories, the current directory, and each of the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable.

The simplest solution is to change the current directory to the DLL Firefox directory. However, that's not thread safe, so I wouldn't rely on it in general. Another option is to append the Firefox directory to the `PATH` environment variable, which is what I suggested in my original version of this answer. However, that's not much better than modifying the current directory.

Newer versions of Windows (NT 6.0+ with update KB2533623) allow the DLL search path to be updated in a thread-safe manner via `SetDefaultDllDirectories`, `AddDllDirectory`, and `RemoveDllDirectory`. But that approach would be over the top here.

In this case, for the sake of both simplicity and compatibility with older versions of Windows, it suffices to call `LoadLibraryEx` with the flag `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH`. You need to load the DLL using an absolute path, else the behavior is undefined. For convenience we can subclass `ctypes.CDLL` and `ctypes.WinDLL` to call `LoadLibraryEx` instead of `LoadLibrary`.

```
import os
import ctypes

if os.name == 'nt':
    from ctypes import wintypes

    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

    def check_bool(result, func, args):
        if not result:
            raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
        return args

    kernel32.LoadLibraryExW.errcheck = check_bool
    kernel32.LoadLibraryExW.restype = wintypes.HMODULE
    kernel32.LoadLibraryExW.argtypes = (wintypes.LPCWSTR,
                                        wintypes.HANDLE,
                                        wintypes.DWORD)

class CDLLEx(ctypes.CDLL):
    def __init__(self, name, mode=0, handle=None, 
                 use_errno=True, use_last_error=False):
        if os.name == 'nt' and handle is None:
            handle = kernel32.LoadLibraryExW(name, None, mode)
        super(CDLLEx, self).__init__(name, mode, handle,
                                     use_errno, use_last_error)

class WinDLLEx(ctypes.WinDLL):
    def __init__(self, name, mode=0, handle=None, 
                 use_errno=False, use_last_error=True):
        if os.name == 'nt' and handle is None:
            handle = kernel32.LoadLibraryExW(name, None, mode)
        super(WinDLLEx, self).__init__(name, mode, handle,
                                       use_errno, use_last_error)
```

Here are all of the available `LoadLibraryEx` flags:

```
DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES         = 0x00000001
LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE            = 0x00000002
LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH       = 0x00000008
LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL        = 0x00000010  # NT 6.1
LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE      = 0x00000020  # NT 6.0
LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE  = 0x00000040  # NT 6.0

# These cannot be combined with LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH.
# Install update KB2533623 for NT 6.0 & 6.1.
LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR    = 0x00000100
LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR = 0x00000200
LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS       = 0x00000400
LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32        = 0x00000800
LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS    = 0x00001000
```

For example:

```
firefox_path = r'F:\Softwares\Mozilla Firefox'
nss3 = CDLLEx(os.path.join(firefox_path, 'nss3.dll'), 
              LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH)

nss3.NSS_GetVersion.restype = c_char_p

>>> nss3.NSS_GetVersion()                 
'3.13.5.0 Basic ECC'
```

Answer (score 11):

Note that the ctypes module works with C extensions; if you want to write code in C++, you might do as follows (the C code is the same):

**Your dll.c source: (you can use C++ code with .cpp extension without any problem)**

```
#include <math.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) double _sin(double x)
{
     return sin(x)
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**Command prompt with Administrator authentication:**

With C source:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cl /LD "your_source_path\dll.c" /I "c:\Python33 \include" "c:\Python33\libs\python33.lib" /link/out:dll.dll
```

With C++ source:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cl /LD "your_source_path\dll.cpp" /I "c:\Python33 \include" "c:\Python33\libs\python33.lib" /link/out:dll.dll
```

**Compiler generates DLL file:**

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

dll.c // or dll.cpp 
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:dll.dll
/dll
/implib:dll.lib
/out:dll.dll
dll.obj
c:\Python33\libs\python33.lib
   Creating library dll.lib and object dll.exp
```

**Your Python module:**

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.CDLL('your_dll_path')
dll._sin.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double]
dll._sin.restype = ctypes.c_double
print(dll._sin(34))


# return 0.5290826861200238
```

Comment: I have struggled getting basic comms running between C++ and python for a combined 12 hours now or so over the span of 2 days. THANK YOU for this answer, as it was finally what I was looking for.

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic, I hope you've since learned to not link python33.lib when your code doesn't use it at all. That your code will eventually be loaded in a Python process doesn't require any compile-time linking to the Python DLL. That would be bizarre and almost completely defeats the point of creating a DLL.

Comment: Tried and it doesn't work. I created the dll 2 ways using dev-C ++ and visual studio with the exact code you provided and it doesn't work. I get error: The specified module could not be found. The error happend on load line in python.

Comment: @Brana give compiled DLL's path to it, it works without any modification.

Comment: Actually it started to work now, C++ didn't work properly on my PC so i compiled od another one. Now i installed visual studio and it works without any problem.

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` was what I missed and caused all my problems... You never need such trash in Linux...

Answer (score 5):

I just had a similar problem with ctypes.CDLL, and I got it to work changing the current directory to the library directory and loading the library only by name (I guess putting the directory in the system path would work too)
So, instead of

```
CDLL('C:/library/path/library.dll')
```

I did

```
os.chdir('C:/library/path')
CDLL('library')
```

Comment: Changing the current directory is ok if you're in a single-threaded process or if you're only loading the DLLs at program startup. In general, changing the working directory isn't thread safe. For an updated Windows Vista+ (i.e. KB2533623 installed), you can instead call [`AddDllDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh310513) and [`SetDefaultDllDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh310515). If `kernel32.AddDllDirectory` doesn't exist, fall back on extending `PATH`.