# Use a DLL with python (using ctypes), not working

Tags: c++, python, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to write a DLL that I can import in Python (2.7), and I'm having difficulties "making it work". When I load the library in Python using `WinDLL()` or `windll.LoadLibrary()`, and test the exported function the output i get is empty. If I add an argument to `TestFunction()` it raises a `ValueError` which states that there is probably to many arguments (it's really not).

**python-file:**

```
from ctypes import *

x = windll.LoadLibrary('./pymod.dll')
print x.TestFunction(123) #Should return 123.
```

**main.h:**

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__
#include <windows.h>
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)    

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

int DLL_EXPORT TestFunction(int data);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

and **main.cpp:**

```
#include "main.h"

int DLL_EXPORT TestFunction(int x = 0) {
    return x;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    switch (fdwReason){
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Solved**: Issue was wrong calling convention.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question/problem, but if you want to make Python modules, I would recommend Boost.Python. Just a thought.

Comment: Could you paste the exact error? I think it should specify a number of excess/missing bytes.

Comment: The exact error is
`ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (4 bytes in excess)`

Comment: you can use my answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586504/python-accessing-dll-using-ctypes/13167362#13167362

Comment: why "./pymod.dll"? is it windows, linux, cygwin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first guess would be that you are using a different calling convention than your Python assumes.

```
int DLL_EXPORT TestFunction(int data);
```

That declaration probably means that `cdecl` calling convention will be used; while use of `windll` makes Python believe that the `stdcall` convention should be used. That effectively changes the way that arguments are passed, and thus makes Python believe that you have passed the wrong number of arguments. This is noted in the [ctypes documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions).

If that's the case, you can do either of the following:

1. Change the calling convention in the C code to `stdcall` (which is used in Windows system DLLs). If you are using MSVC, they have [a doc on developing DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687850.aspx);
2. Change the calling convention expected by the Python code to `cdecl`. This is done by using `cdll` instead of `windll`.