# Defining working directory for ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I use ctypes to call functions in a C DLL. I followed the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980479/python-ctypes-loading-dll-from-from-a-relative-path) and use this to open the library in my wrapper:

```
_lib = CDLL(dirname(__file__)+sep+'library.dll')
```

However the library internally calls another file that is located in the same directory as the DLL. This file cannot be found when I call the wrapper from a different location. I always have to place a copy of the file in the working directory of my python console, which can be very unpractical.

Is there a way to define a working directory for the C DLL called by ctypes?

Comment: any luck with this since you posted it?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I was able to get a program working by using `os.chdir` to change to the DLL's path. That's probably a hack, though.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35403780/125507  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7586821/125507

Answer (score 0):

You can add the dll-path temporarily to the system path:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] = path_to_dlls + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
_lib = CDLL('library.dll')
```