# Ctypes can not find the dll dependency of my loaded dll

Tags: python, c, dll, runtime, ctypes

I have exported my code from C to the myexported.dll .
The myexported.dll in turn depends on platforms/qwindows.dll (QT). Which is in the same directory as myexported.dll

This is how I use ctypes:

```
#myapp.py

from ctypes import *
mydll = WinDLL("myexported.dll")
mydll.independant_foo() #works fine
mydll.dependant_foo() #prompts the error and exits the program (python.exe)
```

When I run the script:

```
python.exe myapp.py
```

everything works fine (non dependant functions) until it calls a function that needs the qwindows.dll. At which point it prompts:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".
>   Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, windows.
>   Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

I tried the following and none of them worked:

- Add the path to the qwindows.dll to the environment both manually and using os.environ['PATH']
- os.chdir("path/to/platforms/qwindows.dll") or os.chdir("path/to/platforms")
- os.path.append("path/to/platforms/qwindows.dll") or os.path.append("path/to/platforms")
- copied qwindows.dll next to myexported.dll

The only case that it worked was copying "platforms/qwindows.dll" next to the python.exe file in my python folder.

There are 10 other similar dlls that can not be found unless they are next to the python.exe file.

How can I force python.exe to see the dlls in the myapp.py directory?

Answer (score -2):

I got the same problem. Just found that answer: [error-when-loading-dll-from-a-different-directory-using-python-ctypes-cdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400804/error-when-loading-dll-from-a-different-directory-using-python-ctypes-cdll)

In short word, modify your `os.environ['PATH']` .