# DLL not found after switching from Python 3.7.6 to Python 3.10.3

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, python-3.10

I am trying to upgrade a library to Python 3.10. Up to now, I have been using 3.7.6.

In my library, I am using DLLs. In the package `__init__.py`, I add the DLL path to the PATH variable. Since I want to have the code compatible with 32 and 64 bit systems, I check the bitness at runtime and add the appropriate DLL folder to the PATH:

```
import os
import sys

# Add libs to PATH environment variable such that DLLs can be loaded.
# Load either x64 or x86 depending on whether we are running a 32/64
# bit system.
package_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
if sys.maxsize > 2**32:
    path_dir = os.path.join(package_directory, 'libs', 'x64')
else:
    path_dir = os.path.join(package_directory, 'libs', 'x86')

os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + path_dir
```

The corrresponding folder structure is

```
package_root
|- libs
   |- x64
      |- libbristolpolled.dll
      ...
   |- x86
      |- libbristolpolled.dll
      ...
```

Then in a sub-package, I am using:

```
from ctypes import CDLL

dll = "libbristolpolled.dll"
_lib_bristlp = CDLL(dll)
```

This has worked fine in 3.7.6 but fails in 3.10.3 with the following error message:

```
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\optoMD\sensor\optical\bristol\dll_api.py", line 37, in <module>
    _lib_bristlp = CDLL(dll)  # The correct DLL
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libbristolpolled.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

If I instead use the absolute path, as the error message suggests, it works:

```
from ctypes import CDLL

dll = r"C:\...\libs\x64\libbristolpolled.dll"
_lib_bristlp = CDLL(dll)
```

What is the reason the old method doesn't work anymore, or how can I make it work again? I'd prefer not to have absolute paths in my code and I liked the fact that I handle the DLL path once in the init file and afterwards I just need to import the DLL using the file name.

Comment: Most likely, a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330863/cant-import-dll-module-in-python/59333711#59333711. If that's the case, please mark it as such

Comment: It's true. That question is very similar and your solution applies to me too. I don't know how to mark it as a related issue, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular features (by adding the path to find a `.dll` to `PATH` environment variable) [has been removed in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#ctypes).  As per the notice, the new function [`os.add_dll_directory`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) is provided; quoting the documentation for the reason for the change:

> *New in version 3.8*: Previous versions of CPython would resolve DLLs using the default behavior for the current process. This led to inconsistencies, such as only sometimes searching `PATH` or the current working directory, and OS functions such as `AddDllDirectory` having no effect.

The more portable solution going forward is to attempt to use that function, alternatively just generate the absolute path as you have current done using `os.path.dirname` and `os.path.join` on the `dll` variable - i.e. to maintain compatibility with prior Python versions; also this assumes those `.dll` files do not have external dependencies, if there are, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586504/python-accessing-dll-using-ctypes/7586821) has a significantly more detail regarding the issues at hand (even with absolute paths - though given that it did appear to work for your program and library, this should not an issue for your use case).

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. I used ```os.add_dll_directory``` instead of editing the PATH variable and everything was running fine. Note that this doesn't seem to be backward compatible with Python 3.7. I used a try-except block and my previous solution as a fall back option.