# When Importing a dll to python using ctypes, istream and ostream can be found, but not iostream. Why?

Tags: python, c++, interop, iostream

When Importing **`c.dll`** to python using **`ctypes`**, and  **`iostream`** has been included in **`a.cpp`**, I encounter the following error:

```
Could not find module 'C:\Test\foo.dll' (or one of its dependencies). 
Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

As explained at [bugs.python.org](https://bugs.python.org/issue39393) this is an ambiguous error, indicative of a deeper issue.

A few quick notes to be thorough:

- the path is correct and using **`exists(path)`** reveals as much.
- **`istream`**, **`ostream`**, and **`cmath`** all link without issue.
- Looking at the contents of **`iostream`**, the only file that **`iostream`** includes other than **`istream`** and **`ostream`** is **`bits/c++config.h`**. However, **`cmath`** also includes **`bits/c++config.h`** and I am still able to load the **`.dll`** in **`python`** with **`cmath`** included.
- I am using Windows 10 x64, ample storage space, relatively new m.2 drive with no reported errors.
- Python version is **`3.10.8`**
- I have tried switching c++ standards (tried all of them) and recompiling.
- I have tried linking using the method and flags [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115249/how-can-call-c-code-in-python-that-uses-iostream).
- I have tried using **`extern "C"__declspec(dllexport)`** instead of **`extern "C"`**
- I am compiling using **`g++`** from **`mingw64`**
- Dependency walker shows nearly 100 missing dependencies, which doesnt make to me, given that it compiles and runs without **`iostream`**.

The contents of my files for reproduction is as follows:

**a.cpp**

```
#include <ostream>
extern "C" void Print()
{
    printf("Hello!");
}
```

**b.py**

```
from ctypes import *

core = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:/Test/c.dll")
core.Print()
```

**makefile**

```
main:
    g++ -shared -o .c.dll .a.cpp
    python3 -B b.py
```

If I compile this using **`make`** it works perfectly, as it should.

However, if I change **`a.cpp`** to the following and compile, I receive the **above noted** error:

**a.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void Print()
{
    printf("Hello!");
}
```

As far as I can tell, the linker cannot find a dependency that I cannot see in the **`mingw64`** version  of **`iostream`**, but that is as much as I can discern.

Does anyone else encounter this error using the above files? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at this moment for python 3.10 the solution for this is to statically link against both `libgcc` and `libstdc++` (or copy them from mingw/bin folder to your dll folder), this doesn't seem to be the case for versions of python prior to 3.10

```
g++ -shared -o c.dll a.cpp -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

it seems like python 3.10 currently doesn't look for those dlls in your `PATH`.

**Edit:** according to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645987/15649230), you have to add the dlls path manually using [`os.add_dll_directory`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory), alternatively you can use CDLL `winmode` parameter to allow windows to search for dlls in your PATH, but it is discouraged, and linking them statically is the best solution to run the dll on systems that don't have mingw installed or on PATH.

```py
core = CDLL(r"c.dll",winmode=0x8)
```

Comment: @Andy [static linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking) is the solution, it puts those libraries content inside your dll, which results in larger dlls, but they are self-contained.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed for that clarification, I appreciate that. I removed the comment I made as it may mislead future readers.